# Grotius and the Orphic verses

Tags: reference-request

This might not be the best place to ask, and I apologize if this is off-topic.

In his of the *Truth of the christian religion*, Hugo Grotius quotes on several occasions the *[Orphic verses](http://books.google.fr/books?id=l-dw-KtxGEEC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=orphic%20verses%20grotius%20demetrius&source=bl&ots=FBR7tSKMJL&sig=C17PptYD2Rfs8q5Onp9KnGzF0HE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1zJ3UILTNcuXhQfft4CwCw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=orphic%20verses%20grotius%20demetrius&f=false)*. I cannot find any reference to this work anywhere else. What is it, and where can they be found (if anywhere)?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphism_(religion)#Mythology) might [help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orpheus#Orphic_poems_and_rites).

Comment: I think you mean these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orpheus#Orphic_poems_and_rites